# Find entrance of matrix for each adjacent pair of numbers in vector and multiply

Tags: matlab

I have a (transition) function defined by a matrix say `P=[0.75,0.25;0.25,0.75]` and I have a vector  say `X=[1,2,1]` then i would like to find `P(1,2)*P(2,1)`. How is the easiest way to generalise this? I tried creating a function handle for `P(i,j)` and then `X_temp=[X(1:end-1);X(2:end)]`, using the function of each column and finally using the product function, but it seems a lot more comprehensive than it has to be.

The X i want to use is 1000 dimensional and P is 3x3 and I would have to repeat it a lot of times so speed I think will matter.

Comment: So for an `X` of 4 values, lets say `X=[1,2,2,1]`, what is the final result? `P(1,2)*P(2,2)*P(2,1)` ?

Comment: That is exactly what i meant!

Comment: Then it's pretty simple, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub2ind` to get your relevant P values:

```
Ps = P(sub2ind(size(P), X(1:end-1), X(2:end)))
```

Now just multiply them all together:

```
prod(Ps)
```

EDIT:

For function handles you had the right idea, just make sure that you function itself handles vectors. For example lets say your function f(i,j) = i + j, I'm going to assume it's actually `f(x) = x(1) + x(2)` but I want it to handle many `x`s at once so`f(x) = x(:,1) + x(:,2)`:

```
f = @(x)(x(:,1) + x(:,2))
f([X(1:end-1)', X(2:end)'])
```

OR

```
f = @(ii, jj)(ii + jj)
f(X(1:end-1)', X(2:end)')  %//You don't actually need the transposes here anymore
```

just note that you need to use element wise operators such as `.*`, `./` and `.^` etc instead of `*`, `/`,`^`...

Comment: That is really great! I know this is something different, but maybe you know aswell. What if I would like to do the same, but where instead of P(i,j) it would be a function handle f(i,j)?

Comment: @Henrik Can you provide a sample `f`?

Comment: This is the one I will need: `f=@(x,y) (1/sqrt(sigma(x)))*exp(-y^2/(2*sigma(x)))`. Whoops. Where sigma is a 3 dim vector [0.1,1,10].

Comment: Probably you need to change `f` to be something along the lines of `f=@(x) (1./sqrt(sigma(x(:,1)))).*exp(-(x(:,2).^2./(2.*sigma(x(:,1))))`. Or else just `f=@(x,y) (1./sqrt(sigma(x))).*exp(-y.^2./(2.*sigma(x)))`